# How to give access to a specific database for a Plesk 11 user

Tags: database, plesk, user-management

So, I've created a user in Plesk 11, and assigned him a role (custom role that a created for him) with only database access.

But this new user has access to all my databases, I want to restrict his access to a specific one.

How can I do this please ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately it's impossible(at least I don't know how) in scope of one subscription(even through direct url), it's possible to just bind this user to one exact subscription and move all other databases in another subscription.

You can add this as feature request to https://plesk.uservoice.com/forums/184549-feature-suggestions

Comment: Thank you Oleg, they should think to add this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Roles give administrative rights to users so Plesk is doing exactly what it was told to do.

Granting administrative DB permissions however does not create a mysql user but a panel user who can manage the databases of the subscriptions you gave him access to ("all" or individually selected).

If you see all databases in phpMyAdmin you are not logged in as this user but clicked a "webadmin" link from within plesk which uses a login-token for the matching db user created for this subscription/database or even the admin (Tools & Settings-> Applications & Databases -> Database Servers -> *Servername* -> Databases) -> "Webadmin" in "Tools" section.

If you see all databases of all subscriptions in Plesk Panel you selected "all" in the "access subscriptions" field when creating the user.

Defining a custom role as an approach for giving access to only one database does not make sense as there is no need for administrative rights (he only could delete his database).

If your intention was to create just a mysql user for a specific database in a specific subscription open subscriber's control panel when logged in as admin user, click "databases", select tab "users", click "add new database user" and select which databases this new user should have access to. done.

Unfortunately for me it is not clear

- where your user sees all the databases
- if "all" really is all of them (like system dbs, too)
- if "access" means control panel or mysql/phpmyadmin

However, I hope i covered all contingencies.